# Hbase connection pool

Tags: java, hbase

I am trying to create hbase connection pool. I have tried the below thing. But I dont know the consequences. Will it affect my performance? Can anybody please help? Hosts can be remote or even local.

```
HashMap cons = new HashMap();
    public void getDataFromHbase(String host, String tableid){
        conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", host);
        ThreadPoolExecutor executor= (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        executor.setMaximumPoolSize(50);
        if(cons.get(host+"tableA_"+tableid) != null){
            table1 = cons.get(host+"tableA_"+tableid);
            table2 = cons.get(host+"tableB_"+tableid);
        }
        else{
            table1 = new HTable(conf,Bytes.toBytes("tableA_"+tableid),executor);
            table2 = new HTable(conf,Bytes.toBytes("tableB_"+tableid),executor);
            cons.put(host+"tableA_"+tableid,table1);
            cons.put(host+"tableB_"+tableid,table2);
        }
        Scan scan = new Scan();
        scan.addFamily(Bytes.toBytes("n"));
        scan.setCaching(1000);
        ResultScanner resultScanner = table1.getScanner(scan);
        ResultScanner resultScannerB = table2.getScanner(scan);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend [HTablePool](https://hbase.apache.org/0.94/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTablePool.html).. rather own connection management which is more **error prone and hard to debug**.

> Class HTablePool
>
> java.lang.Object  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTablePool
>
> All Implemented Interfaces:
>
> Closeable, AutoCloseable
>
> Deprecated.   Use HConnection.getTable(String) instead.
>
> public class HTablePool extends Object implements Closeable
>
> A simple pool of HTable instances. Each HTablePool acts as a pool for
>   all tables. To use, instantiate an HTablePool and use getTable(String)
>   to get an HTable from the pool. This method is not needed anymore,
>   clients should call HTableInterface.close() rather than returning the
>   tables to the pool Once you are done with it, close your instance of
>   HTableInterface by calling HTableInterface.close() rather than
>   returning the tables to the pool with (deprecated)
>   putTable(HTableInterface).  A pool can be created with a maxSize which
>   defines the most HTable references that will ever be retained for each
>   table. Otherwise the default is Integer.MAX_VALUE.
>
> **Pool will manage its own connections to the cluster. See**
>   **HConnectionManager**.

Comment: was my answer useful. you ask questions if you have any.